# Creating Tile UI Like windows phones

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create GridView [like windows 8 phone](http://static.viedegeek.fr/media/2011/06/wp7-mango.jpg), which has live flipping tile. I have seen [QuiltView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/) and [StaggeredGridView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/). But i dont know how to create live tile like windows 8 phone. Can anybody tell me about any library or a nice tutorial?

Comment: What *specifically* is causing you difficulty?

Comment: Making live tile and fliping it.Is my difficulty!. @CommonsWare

Comment: What do you mean by "flipping it?"

Comment: @Cruceo i mean image should flip vertically from center. I have added merto ui screen shot pls see it. http://static.viedegeek.fr/media/2011/06/wp7-mango.jpg

Comment: Sounds like an ndk job to me

Comment: well i am able to create ui like windows 8 but only thing remaining is making that specific grid item(i.e tile) live(animated).@o0rebelious0o

Comment: If you just want the 3D flip animation, take a look at the Rotate3dAnimation classes: https://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.java?r=6

Comment: @Cruceo will it change dynamically?.. I mean after specific time interval i want to flip and change images inside my grid!.

Comment: You'd have to set up a timer or something for that, and then adjust the animation based on each entry